# Angularjs+Typescsript: Best approach to upload file (using controlleras syntax)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, controlleras

I have a working example below, but I think it's not the right approach!

My requirments are:

- I don't want to use external plugins!
- Use controlleras syntax
- Use Typescript

Html:

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)" />
```

Controller:

```
module Test {
    export class TestController {
        MessageUpload: string;
        vm: any;

        static $inject = [ 'Factory','$state', '$scope'];

        constructor(private Factory:IFactory, private $state: ng.ui.IStateService, private $scope: any) {
            $scope.vm = this;
            $scope.uploadFile = this.uploadFile;
            this.vm = this;
        }

        /* ... */
        /* ... */
        /* ... */

        get(){/* .... */}

        uploadFile(files) {
            this.vm.MessageUpload = 'Uploading file. Please wait...';
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', files[0]);

            this.vm.Factory.upload(fd).then((r) => {
                this.vm.MessageUpload = 'Completed ...';
                this.vm.get();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Last note:

- in `uploadFile()`: `this` is referred to `$scope` so I have to pass controller instance somehow to be able to access `MessageUpload` and `get()`. Even in `get()` function `this` is referred to `$scope`.

Does anyone know how to refactor this to be able to achieve uploading and using `this` as reference to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line:
$scope.uploadfile = this.uploadFile;

With:
$scope.uploadFile = (file):void => this.uploadFile(file);

*** this is how to assign the function to the scope ***

Remove the line:
this.vm = this;

Answer (score 0):

`onchange`

There is angular world (`$digest`) and there is the *outside* world (in `v1` atleast). So you can't just use a standard event handler to do stuff.

> I don't want to use external plugins!

Sure. Then *copy* the code from any number of already written plugins.

Comment: Thanks for replying.First The code is working, I want to know how to make it work in a clean way! I don't feel that `this.vm = this;` is the good thing to do.